# Nifi flowfiles stucked in connection while actively balancing

Tags: load-balancing, apache-nifi

I have a 3 nodes cluster(as you can see on attached images) with a connection with a Load Balance Strategy set to Partition by attribute, sometimes some flowfiles get stuck in this connection (see image1). Furthermore we have this log error in bulletin board

{{10:56:28 UTC ERROR xxxx-xxx-xx-nifi0.xxxx:8443 }}

```
10:56:28 UTC ERROR xxxx-xxx-xx-nifi0.xxxx:8443

Failed to communicate with Peer xxxx-xxx-xx-nifi2.xxxx:8443 when load balancing data for Connection with ID c12f3c02-9f05-1232-ffff-fffff8d925a9 due to java.io.IOException: Failed to decrypt data from Peer xxxx-xxx-xx-nifi2.xxxx:8443 because Peer unexpectedly closed connection{}
```

The weird thing is that only some flowfiles are stucked other flowfiles goes forward in the flows.
If I restart nifi service, the problem fix automatically, but it's a very annoying problem.

I think this bug is the same of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-9574
[image: Here are the flowfile stuck in 'actively balancing']
[image: active nifi thread]
[image: Nifi_version]

In addition i have also this log:

```
2022-02-23 11:55:04,939 ERROR org.apache.nifi.controller.queue.clustered.client.async.nio.NioAsyncLoadBalanceClient: Failed to communicate with Peer nifi1:8443
2022-02-23 11:55:04,940 ERROR org.apache.nifi.controller.queue.SwappablePriorityQueue: Updated Size of Queue Unacknowledged from FlowFile Queue Size[ ActiveQueue=[2, 125681 Bytes], Swap Queue=[0, 0 Bytes], Swap Files=[0], Unacknowledged=[-2, -125681 Bytes] ] to FlowFile Queue Size[ ActiveQueue=[2, 125681 Bytes], Swap Queue=[0, 0 Bytes], Swap Files=[0], Unacknowledged=[-2, -125681 Bytes] ]
2022-02-23 11:55:04,959 ERROR org.apache.nifi.controller.queue.clustered.client.async.nio.NioAsyncLoadBalanceClient: Failed to communicate with Peer nifi1:8443
```

and

```
Failed to communicate with Peer nifi0:8443 when load balancing data for Connection with ID b1dd36e2-6aa3-10ce-ac02-a77bf0374d96 due to java.io.IOException: 
Failed to negotiate Protocol Version with Peer nifi0:8443. Recommended version 1 but instead of an ACCEPT or REJECT response got back a response of 101
```

Comment: Where is your content repo mounted? What is the disk usage of that disk? What is `nifi.content.repository.archive.max.usage.percentage` set to?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Content Repo is mounted on ec2 machine, from nifi I can see that repo utilization is 48% both content storage and flowfile storage. 

`nifi.content.repository.archive.max.usage.percentage` is set to 50%

Comment: Is the content repo disk shared with anything else? Try increasing `nifi.content.repository.archive.max.usage.percentage` to something higher like 80 or 90% - does it stop being stuck? This  setting at 50% means that if the disk is 50% full, everything will stop until its below 50% again.

Comment: Sure I will try this config.

Comment: I will check this param when the problem occurs again and then sure I will try this config. 

But the weird thing is that only a small amount of flowfiles is stucked in the queue. Other flowfiles goes on in the right way. In addition all cluster nodes can process flowfiles.

Thanks I will let you know when it happens again.

Comment: Hi the problem has happened again. But that config value has not increased over 50% 
I guess the problem is link to other motiviation.